# Need to format my array in angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, relation, echarts

**Getting my array like below**

```
let myArr=[["529256","88163","50210","11843","19404","39807","25177"]]
```

**I have to format below**

```
let formatArr=[
  ["529256", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
  [undefined, "88163", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
  [undefined, undefined, "50210", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
  [undefined, undefined, undefined, "11843", undefined, undefined, undefined],
  [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "19404", undefined, undefined],
  [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "39807", undefined],
  [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "25177"]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The flat() method creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth.

```js
let myArr = [
  ["529256", "88163", "50210", "11843", "19404", "39807", "25177"]
]

let formatArray = myArr.flat(1).map((number, index, array) => {
  const size = array.length;
  return new Array(size).fill(undefined).map((item, innerIndex) => {
    if (index === innerIndex) {
      return number;
    } else {
      return undefined
    }
  });
})
console.log(formatArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the reduce function to achieve this

```js
let myArr = [
  ["529256", "88163", "50210", "11843", "19404", "39807", "25177"]
]

const newArray = myArr[0].reduce((prev, next, index) => {
  let arr = Array(myArr[0].length).fill(undefined)
  arr[index] = next
  return [...prev, arr]
},[])

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: hi @Owen Kelvin this is my array [
  "529256",
  "88163",
  "50210",
  "11843",
  "19404",
  "39807",
  "25177"
]

Comment: I should format below  [
  ["529256", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
  [undefined, "88163", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
  [undefined, undefined, "50210", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],
  [undefined, undefined, undefined, "11843", undefined, undefined, undefined],
  [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "19404", undefined, undefined],
  [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "39807", undefined],
  [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "25177"]
];

Comment: Which array comes first? Please clarify in your question

Comment: @Sankar, check out my answer

Comment: @OwenKelvin,```` myArr=[["6709"],["1949"],["87484"],["12760"],["13326"],["3356"],["98000"],["16949"],["29981"],["7879"],["117640"],["30727"],["122071"],["21325"],["210406"],["65824"],["2744807"],["56664"],["382719"],["134578"],["2440528"],["83819"],["1362744"],["450092"],["2461"],["336"],["166446"],["16363"]]````

Comment: I have to format below formatArr=  [["6709", "1949", "87484", "12760"],
 ["13326", "3356", "98000", "16949"],
["29981", "7879", "117640", "30727"],
["122071", "21325", "210406", "65824"],
["2744807", "56664", "382719", "134578"]
["2440528", "83819", "1362744", "450092"],
["2461", "336", "166446", "16363"]]

Comment: @Sankar is this a new question?